# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my controller I have loaded the data from 3 models. And 2 model data I have assigning to `TempData`.

```
TempData["RequestDetails"] = appRequest;
TempData["PreApproved"] = PreApproved;
```

Then in the view what I'm doing is, I'm getting data from `TempData` and parsing those data to the partial view.

```
 Asp_PASMVC.Models.AppRequest RequestDetails = (Asp_PASMVC.Models.AppRequest)TempData.Peek("RequestDetails");
```

and

```
@{

    Html.RenderPartial("_RequestView", RequestDetails);
}
```

This is works fine, but when I tried to parse the data as same to other, I'm getting this error

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Asp_PASMVC.Models.ApprovalParty]' to type 'Asp_PASMVC.Models.ApprovalParty'.

The way I did that is:

```
 Asp_PASMVC.Models.ApprovalParty PreApprovedDetails = (Asp_PASMVC.Models.ApprovalParty)TempData.Peek("PreApproved");
```

Any ideas what I did wrong?

Comment: Your trying to cast a List of ApprovalParty to an ApprovalParty object. It should be List<Asp_PASMVC.Models.ApprovalParty> PreApprovedDetails = (Asp_PASMVC.Models.ApprovalParty)TempData.Peek("PreApproved");

Comment: @Zephire I also tried that, But it won't work either. This thing is what I done for the **RequestDetails** is also same way, It works fine. But Not for the **PreApprovedParty**

Comment: @Zephire I got the answer, I changed to ** List<Asp_PASMVC.Models.ApprovalParty> PreApprovedDetails = (List<Asp_PASMVC.Models.ApprovalParty>)TempData.Peek("PreApproved");** and it works. Thanks